# Microsoft Graph NoPermissionsInAccessToken when trying to fetch contacts

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

What I'm trying to do is create a simple Microsoft Azure app that fetches all the contacts with Microsoft Graph. I THINK I understand how it should work, but seeing as I fail to actually make it work, I need some help.

I managed to fetch user data same as documented on their documentation site, but when following similar steps for contacts, I keep getting `NoPermissionsInAccessToken`.

My general workflow is to retrieve a token using:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={clientId}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fdetail
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid+offline_access+profile+user.read+Mail.ReadWrite+Contacts.ReadWrite
```

With this I have acquired authorization code, refresh token and such. Now I plug that token into  `AuthorizationCodeProvider` same as provided in example:

```
AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(
        clientId,
        Arrays.asList("openid", "offline_access", "profile", "user.read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "Contacts.ReadWrite"),
        code,
        "http://localhost:8080/detail",
        NationalCloud.Global,
        tenant,
        secret);

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
        .builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .buildClient();

    IContactCollectionPage contacts = graphClient.me().contacts()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();
```

But when the application tries to execute `get()` from the last function it throws the following:

```
401 : Unauthorized
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Cache-Control : private
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_53"}}
client-request-id : e393d9d1-1eae-44b2-9956-2b97c0105b42
request-id : fecedee8-8b69-44b1-b300-5c9f71d3c427
Content-Length : 284
Date : Thu, 13 Feb 2020 13:12:27 GMT
Content-Type : application/json

{
  "error": {
    "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
    "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "fecedee8-8b69-44b1-b300-5c9f71d3c427",
      "date": "2020-02-13T13:12:27"
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know I have given the application all the necessary grants through `portal.azure.com`. Went to app registration, my application, API permissions, and added delegated Contacts.ReadWrite permission that is documented to be necessary.

Any idea what I can do to make this thing work?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` it is returning an Authorization Code, not an Access Token. You need to exchange that Auth Code for an Access Token via `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

You can find step-by-step instructions for retrieving a token in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#3-get-a-token).

> Your app uses the authorization code received in the previous step to request an access token by sending a `POST` request to the `/token` endpoint.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake while writing the post, however what I need to provide to the AuthorizationCodeProvider is the authorization code, not the token, am I correct in thinking this? Then the IGraphServiceClient should take care of the rest, or at least that's my understanding. I did just now try to put the Access Token instead of Authorization code though. No luck, everything breaks.

Comment: You send the Auth Code to `/token` and get back a JSON object with an `access_token` property. The value in that property is what you need to provide to Graph.

Comment: I've tried that, and I just get:
InvalidAuthenticationToken Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.5.0 Authorization

When I check out AuthorizationCodeProvider constructor, I can see that it indeed takes auth code instead of access token. What you say does hold true if I weren't using IGraphServiceClient. However IGraphServiceClient later on trades the auth code for token, so I don't have to do that.